# Get dictionary with key/value in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "hello",
        "value": "world"
    },
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "value": "bar"
    }
]
```

What's the pythonic way of fetching the dictionary where `name = "foo"` from a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Will there always be one match? What do you want if there are zero or multiple matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your list of dicts is stored as variable `l`, you can use `next()` with a generator expression like this, which returns the first dict whose `name` key is `foo`:

```
next(d for d in l if d['name'] == 'foo')
```

This will otherwise raise `StopIteration` if there is no dict in `l` with a `name` key that equals `foo`.

Comment: I'll add that `next` also accepts an optional second param, which is the default value to return. So if you do `next(iterator, None)` you can receive the item you are looking for, or `None` if nothing was found - just in case you don't feel like catching exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example.

```
data = [
    {
        "name": "hello",
        "value": "world"
    },
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "value": "bar"
    }
  ]


for item in data:
    if item['name'] == 'foo':
        print(item)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'foo', 'value': 'bar'}
```